# add service reference and internal/public access level

Tags: c#, asp.net, service-reference

I have a two wcf services which I opaque in a library with my api. In the library I added a references to these services with the access level set to internal, because I want only my custom api to be visible in clients, where this library is used. Unfortunatelly I see, I can set the access level to internal only for all classes without any exception. I want to set a two enums to public, because I'm using it as a parameters in my api. If I manually change the internal to public in the generated classes (by add service reference), every time I want to update the service reference, I must remember to change these two enums manually from internal to public. Is it possible to do it automatic?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you expose your own public enum and cast that to the service reference's enum when calling the service?

It's not encouraged to change generated code, just for the problem you're now running into.

Comment: I can do that, but if I add some fields to these two enums the I have to remember to add them in two places.

Comment: @Iszk: for another solution I'd need more detail of your solution structure, but can't you change the enums' access modifier to public in the library, and then select "reuse types" when adding the service reference?